# RecyclerView smoothScrollToPosition returning wrong position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-scrollview

In my recyclerView, I want to scroll by position with animation. I wrote custom LinearLayoutManager.

Here is my code

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 200f;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                   RecyclerView.State state, final int position) {

        LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller =
            new LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {
                @Override
                public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition
                (int targetPosition) {
                    return CustomLayoutManager.this
                            .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                }
                @Override
                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
                (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                    return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                }
            };

        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }
}
```

I'm using this class like this.

```
leaderBoardAdapter = new SPGamificationLeaderBoardAdapter(response.list, getContext());
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.setAdapter(leaderBoardAdapter);
    CustomLayoutManager layoutManager = new CustomLayoutManager(getContext());
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.post(() -> {
        leaderBoardRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        leaderBoardRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        leaderBoardRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(10);


    });
```

The animation is working perfectly, but `smoothScrollToPosition` is returning the wrong position. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

`return CustomLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);`

TO

`return CustomLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(position);`